# How to loop through values in a CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to pass a list of comma separated parameters in an AWS CloudFormation template and create multiple Amazon S3 buckets based on those values.

I have a requirement where I will be passing a comma separated- list of country names and then the CloudFormation template would build that many S3 buckets (based on the names of countries passed in parameters).

For example, if I pass `fr,us,gb` in a parameter, the stack should create `fr_myprod_bucket`, `us_myprod_bucket`, `gb_myprod_bucket`.

I know there is no for loop in CloudFormation, so not sure how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you wanting to create those buckets in different regions?

Comment: No in the same region

Comment: Since July 2023: [Fn::ForEach - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/ is another option for adding for-loops to CloudFormation templates. You will need to render the Jinja template before passing it to CloudFormation, as CloudFormation itself cannot currently process Jinja templates.

```
  {% for country in ["fr", "us", "gb"] %}
  {{country}}_myprod_bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  {% endfor %}
```

Rendering that Jinja snippet would produce:

```
  fr_myprod_bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  us_myprod_bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  gb_myprod_bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [Count macro](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Count)!

> The Count macro provides a template-wide Count property for CloudFormation resources. It allows you to specify multiple resources of the same type without having to cut and paste.

Thus, the the following:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: Count
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: TestKey
          Value: my bucket %d
    Count: 3
```

Would be equivalent to:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  Bucket1:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: TestKey
          Value: my bucket 1
  Bucket2:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: TestKey
          Value: my bucket 2
  Bucket3:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: TestKey
          Value: my bucket 3
```

Comment: This requires installing the Count macro in your AWS account.
Refer : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Count

Comment: Now you can use for each function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach.html

Answer (score 8):

This is now possible using `Fn::ForEach`. See the [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/07/accelerate-cloudformation-authoring-experience-looping-function/) and [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach.html) for details.

You could do something like below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Create multiple Amazon S3 buckets using prefix from a comma delimited list
Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
Parameters:
  CountryNames:
    Description: Country prefix names
    Default: "fr,gb,us"
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
Resources:
  'Fn::ForEach::S3Buckets':
    - ParamName
    - !Ref CountryNames
    - 'Bucket${ParamName}':
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketName: !Sub '${ParamName}-my-prod-bucket-${AWS::Region}-${AWS::AccountId}'
          ## Add more configuration parameters for the buckets here...
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use [CDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk), which wraps CloudFormation in Typescript, Python, Java, .NET or Golang.

Comment: CDK only let's you have flow-control when compiling, not at run-time.

Comment: @Tom Yes I should have clarified that in order to use CDK for this you would have to use CDK a level above the CloudFormation. The "compiling" (synth) can happen when you like though. And you can bring (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/use_cfn_template.html) CloudFormation in to your CDK .

Answer (score 1):

AWS now supports For loop in cloudformation for resources

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
Resources:
  'Fn::ForEach::Bucket': 
    - BucketName
    - - 'fr'
      - 'gb'
      - 'us'
    - 'MyBucket${BucketName}': ##resource name
        Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
        Properties:
          BucketName: !Sub ${BucketName}_myprod_bucket

# Require CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND, IAM with custom resources capability
```

Comment: You can find the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach.html and examples here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-foreach-example-resource.html