# How to add email subscription of SNS Topic on CloudFormation Script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

```
  TestTopicSubscription:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  Properties:
    Endpoint: testn@email.com
    Protocol: email
    TopicArn: !Ref TestSnsTopic
```

How to add subscription for multiple email ids(eg:test1@email.com,test2@email.com) to the above list?

Comment: How about creating several subscriptions?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195157/how-to-loop-through-values-in-a-cloudformation-template

Comment: How you tried Macros?

Comment: I've noticed that most of your questions have answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Comment: very old topic but a custom backed lambda is the perfect solution for this - I can share a code snippet with you if this is still required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no loops in CloudFormation, and [AWS::SNS::Subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html) does not take any lists.

So your choices are:

1. Use AWS CLI or SDK to **programmatically** create a number of stacks based on a single template. The template would be parameterized, where the parameter would be your endpoint. Thus, using bash or python, for instance, you would have to iterate over your list and create corresponding subscriptions.
2. Creating a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation to take your list of emails and create corresponding subscription. The resource would be in the form of a **lambda function** which would use AWS SDK to create needed subscriptions.
3. Instead of custom resource, you could also create [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) in CloudFormation.
4. Manually copy-and-paste the subscriptions template, if you have only few of them in a single template.

Comment: There are no loops, but there are macros using which we can achieve looping.

Comment: @robert Thanks. Forgout about them I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Hello @Marcin, can you please look at this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67886902/awssns-email-customize-sns-subscribe-confirmation-email-for-any-topic

Comment: @Marcin It helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug 2022, this is now possible using a lambda function with an input parameter that specifies the email endpoints for the SNS topic. Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/subscribe-multiple-email-endpoints-to-an-sns-topic-by-using-a-custom-resource.html