# AWS:SNS Email - Customize SNS Subscribe Confirmation Email for any topic

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sns

Anyone have an idea, how can I change the SNS subscription confirmation email template?

User Interaction Step By Step to understand the exact question: (All action done using AWS PHP SDK)

1> User A created campaign in AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/sns-examples-managing-topics.html#create-a-topic

2> Added N number of subscribers to the campaign: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/sns-examples-subscribing-unsubscribing-topics.html#subscribe-an-email-address-to-a-topic

3> All of the subscribers will receive an email from AWS SNS saying that, you have opt-in to the ARN:TOPICNAME. Click on the confirmation link to verify subscription

***The question related to this place: When adding a subscriber to the campaign, SNS send an email with a verification link with its own branding. I want to change the template of the email and want to add our own branding to the email. How can I do that?***

**[image: Image text]**

4> Each subscriber will open the email and confirm a subscription.
Another one:
Is there any way to stop double opt-in as users have prevalidated emails to receive an email from us?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would subscribe a Lambda to the SNS topic and then in the Lambda you would use AWS SES to send your email in a format that you require.

Comment: @SahilPatel. Look at these links https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-api.html, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-formatted.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-raw.html. The last link has Java and Python code examples how to send the email. For the token - you can get that from the event payload in the Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I did here...

I tried to create email campaign with pub sub module on SNS

WHICH IS WRONG.

THE QUESTION IS MEANING LESS

As AWS sns is only send SIMPLE TEXT EMAIL as notifications.