# How to create multiple cloudformation stacks where a single parameter changes?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-sam, infrastructure-as-code

I want to enter a list of cities as parameters to a SAM template. For Example: London, New York, Dubai. The list can have a large number of cities, say 50.

Using this list of cities, I want to create a log group pertaining to each city. For example:

- /aws/ecs/Dubai
- /aws/ecs/London
- /aws/ecs/New York

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Count Macro](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Count) in Cloudformation.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: Count
Resources:
   Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
   Properties: 
       LogGroupName: /aws/ecs/%s
   Count: ['Dubai','London','NewYork']
```

For more information check this question: [How to loop through values in a CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195157/how-to-loop-through-values-in-a-cloudformation-template)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually used the Explode macro in CloudFormation to solve this problem:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Explode