# enumerating availability zones for ECS cluster VPC subnets in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, availability-zone

When I manually create an AWS ECS cluster in the UI, by default it shows the default VPC with the default subnets selected, one in each availability region, which I infer to be best practice.

I'm creating a new ECS Fargate deployment using CloudFormation, and I believe the best practice is to create a new VPC with its own subnets, similarly each in a different availability zone.

Rather than hard-coding them in CloudFormation, how can I enumerate the availability zones for the current region and create subnets for each of them?

I'm new to CloudFormation. I've seen that there is a built-in function to enumerate availability zones, so with some thought I'm sure I can figure this out on my own. And I'll be sure to add that as an answer here. But being what surely is a common use case, perhaps there is an existing best-practices template somewhere that already shows how to do that so I don't have to reinvent it. (I haven't been able to find it immediately by searching.)

Comment: This is not really an ECS or Fargate question. This is a CloudFormation VPC creation question.

Comment: I highly recommend using this website for generating Infrastructure as Code snippets for Terraform and CloudFormation: https://asecure.cloud/ For example here's a snippet of CloudFormation that creates a VPC https://asecure.cloud/p/securevpc/

Comment: "I highly recommend using this website …" Thank you for tips on general resources and template libraries. However I can't find anything on that web site that answers my question, or explains how to do it. The specific snippet you mentioned is interesting, and it shows techniques that will no doubt come in handy in the future, but still it manually includes two subnets and manually selects the first two availability zones (assuming there are two availability zones), which is perhaps a step forward but still not what I desire.

Comment: From the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/q/57195157, it would appear that CloudFormation doesn't support this for-each concept in general.  (Some claim that declarative templating frameworks can't support this by definition, but I disagree.)

Comment: Terraform does support what you are looking for.

Comment: So it looks like the technique of manually indicating `AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region]` and `AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, Fn::GetAZs: !Ref AWS::Region]` (and assuming there are at least two availability zones in the region) is as close as I'm going to get in CloudFormation to what I was looking for. @MarkB if you want to write that as an answer I can mark it as accepted if nothing better comes along. And thanks again for pointing me to that snippet; it was helpful to define the routing table and gateway. I'll check out the other snippets there as well.